# Django: distutils errors when installing requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, django-1.4

I am trying to setup my app in a fresh computer but I am having trouble installing the `requirements.txt` file.

It fails when trying to install this package in particular:

```
django-generic-m2m==0.2.2
```

I tried running `pip install django-generic-m2m==0.2.2` and indeed I got the same error message, which is an exception thrown by the `convert_path(pathname)` method in the `utils.py` file from `distutils`.

I really don't know what do to. These are not my files, so how can I even figure out how to fix the scripts?

Has anybody had this problem in the past? Any suggestions?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on empty virtual environment. Try to update your setuptools.

Comment: @zymud I ran `pip install setuptools --upgrade` and it says it is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in the package, they fixed it in the version 0.3.1.